# Is it OK to watch movie at work on break time?

Tags: work-environment, break-time

I always used to eat my lunch behind my desk and watch movies simultaneously from 12:50 TO 13:30 pm. It was OK until this behavior gradually  spread to my coworkers, and after a while all employees  watched movies during their lunch time. Two days ago our manager announced that during lunch time all monitors should be turned off and using mobile is prohibited .

I'm so bored with this new rule and want to know is this rule common in other companies? If this is a time to break off from work and get a little rest, don't I deserve to decide how to rest or break?

How can I protest against this rule?

Comment: "I fear the day that technology will surpass our human interaction. The world will have a generation of idiots " Albert Einstein.   Maybe your boss wants you to talk to each-other?

Comment: Is it ok to watch movies in the workplace?  I think so.  Is it ok to watch movies in YOUR workplace?  No; your manager has already clarified that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Companies normally have a reason for these sorts of policies. For example, not everybody takes lunch at the same time and if a client walked in and saw your monitor with a movie on it, they might not be impressed. This in turn might be a bad reflection on your company and may result in loss of future business if they think they're paying for slacking off.

If you really wanted to watch a movie, I would suggest going somewhere off-site, such as a park bench or something and using your phone there. The bottom line is your manager said no and protesting it may result in career-limiting prospects.

There are always rules that folk disagree with, but 9/10 there are reasons they have been implemented in the first place. Very rarely will managers get together and think "How can we inconvenience OP today?"

Answer (score 9):

Your manager has said no so the answer is no.  It's as simple as that.

The reason he's (probably) doing it is that with so many people streaming films, the internet speed becomes too slow for anyone using the internet for work related things (ie, those earning the company money) cannot work.

At my workplace we are allowed to surf the internet at lunch times but streaming is forbidden.

Comment: While this is certainly correct, it doesn't explain why the employees should be forbidden from watching movies on their own mobile during break times. You might choose to expand your answer a bit to cover that.

Comment: no, it doesn't relate to Internet speed, Internet traffic is controlled and limited, we watch movies offline

Answer (score 7):

> Is it OK to watch movie at work on break time?

Typically companies will have a policy around internet and equipment usage, but the best way to be sure is to ask your manager.  You manager has done one better for you in this regards and **said no, so move along**.

If you want to use your mobile, go out to your car and use it.  Your manager cannot tell you what to do on *your break if you are not on company property*.

If your interested in **training**, ask your manager about training videos.  These would benefit you and the company, plus have **added the benefit of passing the time**.